# Bison terminating instead of shifting error

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison

I have a grammar that works well except that it doesn't tolerate syntax errors. I'm trying to work in `error` tokens so that it can gracefully recover. I've read through [the Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Error-Recovery) on error recovery but something is not adding up.

Here's a snippet from the grammar:

```
%start start
%token WORD WORDB SP CRLF

%%

start : A B C
      | error CRLF start

A     : WORD SP WORD CRLF

...
```

Here's a snippet of the output file that `bison` produces describing the grammar

```
State 0

    0 $accept: . start $end

    error  shift, and go to state 1
    WORD   shift, and go to state 2

    start      go to state 3
    A          go to state 4

State 1

    2 start: error . CRLF start

    CRLF  shift, and go to state 5

State 5

    2 start: error CRLF . start

    error  shift, and go to state 1
    WORD   shift, and go to state 2

    start     go to state 25
    A         go to state 4
```

Given the input tokens `WORDB CRLF WORD SP WORD CRLF .....` I would expect the state transitions to be `0 -> 1 -> 5 -> 2 -> ...`, but when I run the parser it actually produces the following:

```
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--accepting rule at line 49 ("WORDB")
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: Next token is token WORDB ()
syntax error, unexpected WORDB, expecting WORD
```

As best I can tell, if the parser is in State 0 and it sees a token  other than `WORD` it should interpret the token as if it was `error` and should go to State 1. In practice it is just hard failing.

Comment: What does your `yyerror()` function do? The `error` transition does not suppress the call to `yyerror()`.

Comment: `exit(1)`. Welp. That'll do it. I had given up on debugging the generated parser since the variable names are so incredibly terse.

Comment: OK, made an answer out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error` transition does not suppress the call to `yyerror()`, so if your `yyerror` implementation does something like call `exit()`, error recovery will not be able to proceed.